# Output parameters may only be mapped through the RowsAffectedParameter property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure in which I want to return the output value and access it on the application in which I am accessing it through the Entity Framework.

My Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Insert_StudentDetails]
(
    @Name varchar(150),
    @City varchar(150),
    @ReturnValue int OUT
)

as
Begin
    --Declare 
    if NOT exists(Select Name  from Student
    WHERE Name=@Name    
    AND City=@City)
    begin
    Insert into Student(Name, City)
    values(@Name, @City)        
    set @ReturnValue=1
    end
    else
    begin
    set @ReturnValue=0
    end
    select @ReturnValue
End
```

Now after right click on the table in edmx file it is showing as the following:

[image]

When I import the function I choose none in return.

I am accessing it by the following code:

```
 public bool insertstudentdata(Student student)
    {
        using (CollegeDataEntities context = new CollegeDataEntities())
        {
            ObjectParameter ReturnedValue = new ObjectParameter("ReturnValue", typeof(int));
            context.InsertStudentData(student.Name, student.City, ReturnedValue);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(ReturnedValue) == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

While running, it is showing the following exception:

[image]

In the Error List, the following exception is also coming:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I solved it.

I changed the last line of my Stored Procedure:

```
select @ReturnValue= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

After updating the model, in the mapping part, I just added the `ReturnValue` in the Result Column Bindings to. Just hit the enter button after writing the out value. Please tick the adjacent checkbox of out value

[image]